# Using a specific Java security provider only in the scope of a method

Tags: java, bouncycastle

So I am looking ways to use a security provider only in the scope of a function. I can already do this by adding these two lines: (assume BouncyCastle is the provider)

```
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");
// do some stuff with converter
Security.removeProvider("BC");
```

So i just want to use BC for JcaPEMKeyConverter and then for the rest use default security provider.

Is there a better way to do this? More elegantly? How about a custom java annotation, is that a good way ?

Thx :)

Comment: I don't know if it's elegant, but you can call the other overload of `.setProvider` with the BC `Provider` object instead of changing the (JVM-global) provider list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want that the `BouncyCastleProvider` are used in [`JcaPEMKeyConverter`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openssl/jcajce/JcaPEMKeyConverter.html) class use [`setProvider(java.security.Provider provider)`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openssl/jcajce/JcaPEMKeyConverter.html#setProvider(java.security.Provider)) instead of [`setProvider(java.lang.String providerName)`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openssl/jcajce/JcaPEMKeyConverter.html#setProvider(java.lang.String)) as follows:

```
JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

Then there is no need to add and remove the provider on the security providers list, so you can avoid `Security.addProvider` and `Security.removeProvider` calls.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Please be aware of the possible memory leak: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8168469